# How Would You Structure This HTML/CSS Template in NextJS?

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is a mockup for a blog post where some featured text is located in a container that has the text floating around it and it also appears to overflow outside of the regular container into the parent container.

This is being built in ReactJS as a template with content being populated from Sanity (a JS CMS). So I'm wondering how you'd structure your markup and then your styling?

**A few notes worth sharing:**

- We're calling this "pull text", not sure if there are other common names for it.
- The yellow bar at the top is the hero image and indicates the full width of the content
- On mobile, the featured text stops floating and acts as a regular block element similarly extending to the far right of the parent container
- Blog content varies in length, some might be very short, others might be very long.

**My initial ideas are:**

- Use CSS grid and allow the featured text to flow out of the center column into the far-right column.
- Float might work with a negative margin-right

Comment: seems to me that it is a simple use of `float`

Comment: Just do `float: right` with a negative right margin to push it beyond the right bounds of the container. There is no reason to use `position: absolute` here. Also, reacts and nextjs aren't relevant to your question: it's a purely CSS one.

Comment: the HTML markup for the infobox is just between the first and second paragraph.

Comment: That's not something CSS can do: you cannot arbitrarily decide a placement of a piece of text, and then let other content flow around it. Your visuals suggest the quote being placed right after the first paragraph. In fact, if your absolute positioning trick works... how're going to deal with very wide or narrow screen? Then the quote will easily appear disconnected/out of context relative to the text around it.

Comment: Thanks @Terry, I've reconsidered vertical implementation and I'm thinking I'll just apply a unique class to that block so that the author will determine the best placement in the WYSIWYG